# When would os.environ['foo'] not match os.getenv('foo')?

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables, freebsd

I have a small Python application, launched via `subprocess.Popen`, that takes some parameters in the form of environment variables.  I do this by passing the environment structure into the `Popen` call.  The program then reads the variables via `os.getenv`.

Or rather, it used to read them that way.  On Windows, it worked fine.  But on our FreeBSD servers, `os.getenv` returns `None` for all the parameters we passed in.  The odd part is that `os.environ` has the values just fine—and, indeed, simply switching all `os.getenv('foo')` calls to `os.environ['foo']` made everything work just fine on *both* platforms.

Why are these values different?  When is one appropriate over the other?

Answer (score 38):

`os.environ` is created on import of the `os` module, and doesn't reflect changes to the environment that occur afterwards unless modified directly. Interestingly enough, however, `os.getenv()` doesn't actually get the most recent environment variables either, at least not in CPython. You see, in CPython, `os.getenv()` is apparently just a wrapper around `os.environ.get()` (see http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6671c5039e15/Lib/os.py#l646). So it seems the main reason to use `os.getenv()` with the stated implementation is when you want to have a default value returned when an environment variable name isn't found in `os.environ`'s keys rather than have a `KeyError` or whatever thrown, and you want to save a few characters.

It's entirely possible that the implementation on FreeBSD has some weird gimmick that causes it to act differently, but I'm not sure why that would be the case. Take a look at the copy of `os.py` on one of the FreeBSD machines you use, if you can.

Comment: On Windows 10, `os.putenv('abc', '123')` did not work, that is, the new variable is not set. However, `os.environ['abc'] = '123'` works and subsequently `os.getenv('abc')` works as well.

Comment: @arvindpdmn After another examination, that's because `putenv()` doesn't actually store the environment variable in `os.environ`; rather, `environ.__setitem__()` calls `putenv()` and also stores the data locally, and neither `getenv()` nor `environ.__getitem__()` actually query the environment itself, they operate off of whatever `os.environ` has stored. Quite a confusing way to implement it.