# Difference between os.getenv and os.environ.get

Tags: python, environment-variables, python-os

Is there any difference at all between both approaches?

```
>>> os.getenv('TERM')
'xterm'
>>> os.environ.get('TERM')
'xterm'

>>> os.getenv('FOOBAR', "not found") == "not found"
True
>>> os.environ.get('FOOBAR', "not found") == "not found"
True
```

They seem to have the exact same functionality.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

See [this related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952507/when-would-os-environfoo-not-match-os-getenvfoo). Basically, `os.environ` is found on import, and `os.getenv` is a wrapper to `os.environ.get`, at least in CPython.

EDIT: To respond to a comment, in CPython, `os.getenv` is basically a shortcut to `os.environ.get` ; since `os.environ` is loaded at import of `os`, and only then, the same holds for
`os.getenv`.

Comment: Indeed, it is, according to the official doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

Comment: From the linked related thread: "the main reason to use `os.getenv()` [...] is when you want to have a default value returned when an environment variable name isn't found in `os.environ`'s keys rather than have a `KeyError` or whatever thrown, and you want to save a few characters."

Comment: `os.environ.get` does not throw `KeyError`.

Answer (score 182):

One difference (observed in Python 2.7 and 3.8) between `getenv()` and `environ[]`:

- `os.getenv()` does not raise an exception, but returns None
- `os.environ.get()` similarly returns None
- `os.environ[]` raises an exception if the environmental variable does not exist

Comment: The OP asks about `os.environ.get()` which returns `None` (unless specified differently) and never raises an exception if the env. var. doesn't exists. Your confusing things with using `os.environ['TERM']` which is not what the question is about.

Comment: The OP's *question* asks about `os.environ.get()` vs `os.getenv()` but the *body* also includes `os.environ` vs. `os.environ.get()` so this answer correct in at least some ways - incomplete, but correct.

Comment: This incorrect and misleading answer should have received negative down votes. The next answer is the right one.

Comment: Someone edited this answer to "fix" it and now there are a bunch of old downvotes and comments on it... It would have been better to just downvote it and post the fix in a new anwer.

Comment: @nyuszika7h - The older revisions were vague - they simple said `os.environ` would raise an exception if the variable didn't exist. They didn't clearly say `os.environ[]` which is what we're now praising as being correct, or `os.environ.get()` which is what I think some people were assuming was meant and criticizing as being wrong. The latest update clearly mentions both of them and accurately describes all of their behaviors.

Answer (score 66):

While there is no functional difference between `os.environ.get` and `os.getenv`, there is a *massive* difference between `os.putenv` and setting entries on `os.environ`. `os.putenv` is **broken**, so you should default to `os.environ.get` simply to avoid the way `os.getenv` encourages you to use `os.putenv` for symmetry.

`os.putenv` changes the actual OS-level environment variables, but in a way that doesn't show up through `os.getenv`, `os.environ`, or any other stdlib way of inspecting environment variables:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['asdf'] = 'fdsa'
>>> os.environ['asdf']
'fdsa'
>>> os.putenv('aaaa', 'bbbb')
>>> os.getenv('aaaa')
>>> os.environ.get('aaaa')
```

You'd probably have to make a ctypes call to the C-level `getenv` to see the real environment variables after calling `os.putenv`. (Launching a shell subprocess and asking it for its environment variables might work too, if you're very careful about escaping and `--norc`/`--noprofile`/anything else you need to do to avoid startup configuration, but it seems a lot harder to get right.)

Comment: It really strikes me to find out that `os.putenv` is actually broken, while I had been using it and thought it were the recommended way, since it's just there, together with `os.getenv`. Shouldn't Python fix this? :/ (I'm using 3.11)

Answer (score 55):

In Python 2.7 with iPython:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getenv??
Signature: os.getenv(key, default=None)
Source:
def getenv(key, default=None):
    """Get an environment variable, return None if it doesn't exist.
    The optional second argument can specify an alternate default."""
    return environ.get(key, default)
File:      ~/venv/lib/python2.7/os.py
Type:      function
```

So we can conclude `os.getenv` is just a simple wrapper around `os.environ.get`.

Comment: In python3, when I do  os.getenv?? I am getting the following error
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    os.getenv??

Comment: @thanos.a I use iPython syntax

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the answers above:

```
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'import os' 'os.environ.get("TERM_PROGRAM")'
200000 loops, best of 5: 1.65 usec per loop

$ python3 -m timeit -s 'import os' 'os.getenv("TERM_PROGRAM")'
200000 loops, best of 5: 1.83 usec per loop
```

EDIT: meaning, no difference

Comment: Which version of Python have you tested with. On 3.7.2, `os.getenv` is just a wrapper for `os.environ.get`, so I am getting very minimal overhead.

Comment: That was 3.7.1 on macOS Mojave. Timings were pretty consistent.

Comment: @PreslavRachev minimal or not it is an extra function call, so there is some overhead. That being said, you probably don't need to retrieve env variables in the middle of your inner loop.

Comment: Totally irrelevant. Micro-optimization of a single function call... Any application should read the environment only on bootstrap anyways, making this even more irrelevant.

Comment: BTW, `usec` is a _microsecond_ in `timeit`. The difference found in this micro-benchmarking was 0.18 microseconds...