# os.environ.get('key') and os.getenv('key') which one should I use?

Tags: python

I am trying to access environment variables using python and I don't know which function should I use `os.getenv` or `os.environ.get`?

**Already referred** : [Difference between os.getenv and os.environ.get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924471/difference-between-os-getenv-and-os-environ-get)

I have enviroment variables like this and want to use them so which function mentioned above will be preferable?

```
USERNAME=johndoe
PASSWORD=johndoepass
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are equivalent. Unfortunately, that other question has an incorrect answer as the accepted answer...

Comment: @Chris neither raises an exception. `dict.get` returns `None` if the key does not exist. Indeed, I believe `os.getenv` is just a convenience function implemented as `os.environ.get(key)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That is [literally](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/os.py#L769) the case.

Answer (score 5):

Use `os.environ`, not because of any functional difference, but because `os.putenv` is broken and using `os.getenv` will encourage you to use `os.putenv`.

`os.putenv` updates the actual OS-level environment variables, but in a way that isn't visible through `os.getenv`, `os.environ`, or any other stdlib way of inspecting environment variables:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['asdf'] = 'fdsa'
>>> os.environ['asdf']
'fdsa'
>>> os.putenv('aaaa', 'bbbb')
>>> os.getenv('aaaa')
>>> os.environ.get('aaaa')
```

Comment: I'd add this answer to the duplicate. The accepted one there is just plain wrong

Comment: It's not so much that `os.putenv` is broken, but that there is an asymmetry between `os.getenv` and `os.putenv`; the former operates on a "mirror" of the environment, and `os.putenv` does not. Using `os.environ` ensures that both the "real" environment and the mirror get updated.

Comment: @chepner: That wouldn't bother me so much if they'd actually given us a way to look past `os.environ` to the real environment variables, but `os.getenv` still looks at the mirror. It might be more accurate to call `os.environ` and `os.getenv` broken, or to call Python's whole environment variable access system broken; it's a matter of perspective.