# Trying to connect a local Azure function to a local Docker instance of Mongo, but keep getting server selection errors

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, azure, azure-functions, pymongo

I was expecting to run the function normally, being able to connect to the database, but it keeps returning Server selection errors, I've tried using both localhost and 172.17.0.2 (which is the docker inspect result), and it simply won't connect. The issue isn't the database as I can connect to it just fine through both localhost and 172.17.0.2.

I have added the MONGO_URL env var to the local.settings.json, and it is being grabbed since it says it failed to connect to the right IP

```py
env = os.getenv("MONGO_URL")
client = pymongo.MongoClient(env)
db = client["data"]
col = db["objects"]
```

Also, weirdly enough, I've tried to print stuff before the client invocation when I was trying to debug it, and the connection would run before the print statements, even though they were placed before the connection

```
[2023-05-31T16:04:33.213Z] Executed 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Failed, Duration=30422ms)
[2023-05-31T16:04:33.213Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTrigger1. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
[2023-05-31T16:04:33.213Z] Exception: ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 172.17.0.2:27017: timed out, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('172.17.0.2', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('172.17.0.2:27017: timed out')>]>
```

I think it's fine, but just in case, here's my local.settings.json

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://172.17.0.2:27017"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have referred link MSDOC Azure Cosmos DB for [MongoDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/introduction) and [Azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/)

- Rather than using [URL](https://i.imgur.com/wHuVPq9.png) connecting with [ConnectionString](https://i.imgur.com/XGu5iW9.png).

**Code:**

```py
connection_string = os.environ["MongoConnectionString"]
try:

client = MongoClient(connection_string)

db = client['your_database_name']

collection = db['your_collection_name']

documents = collection.find()

for  document  in  documents:
logging.info(document)

return  func.HttpResponse("Data retrieved successfully.")

except  pymongo.errors.PyMongoError as  e:

logging.error('Error connecting to Azure Cosmos DB: %s',  str(e))

return  func.HttpResponse("Error connecting to Azure Cosmos DB.",  status_code=500)
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

- For more information for [Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-custom-container?tabs=docker%2Cazure-cli&pivots=azure-functions) [instance](https://mcr.microsoft.com/en-us/product/azure-functions/python/about)

Comment: I believe I am connecting through the connection string? It's a mongodb:// and not a https://. I simply named the environment variable Mongo URL but I do believe I am using the connection string

Comment: Hello @Podpah try my code

Comment: I'll give it a try but it seems like we have the same things

```python
env = os.getenv("MONGO_URL")
client = pymongo.MongoClient(env)
db = client["data"]
col = db["objects"]
```

```python
connection_string = os.environ["MongoConnectionString"]
client = MongoClient(connection_string)
db = client['your_database_name']
collection = db['your_collection_name']
```
os.getenv is a wrapper for os.environ.get https://stackoverflow.com/a/16924553/21999308
We are both using MongoClient to connect, and we are choosing database/collection in the same way

Comment: I have just tried your code, I am still getting the server selection error

Comment: other method ```def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    # Obtain the connection string for your Azure Cosmos DB account
    connection_string = 'connection string'

    try:
        # Create a MongoClient object and pass in the connection string
        client = MongoClient(connection_string)

        # Access a specific database within your Cosmos DB account
        db = client['sampath']

    ```

Comment: ```documents = collection.find()
        for document in documents:
            logging.info(document)

        return func.HttpResponse("Data retrieved successfully.")
    except pymongo.errors.PyMongoError as e:
        logging.error('Error connecting to Azure Cosmos DB: %s', str(e))
        return func.HttpResponse("Error connecting to Azure Cosmos DB.", status_code=500)

```

Comment: Console [Output](https://i.imgur.com/WZ3khc9.png) URL [Output](https://i.imgur.com/H7QtOiG.png) for time out Troubleshoot refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/recover-python-functions?tabs=vscode%2Cbash&pivots=python-mode-configuration)

Comment: even by removing the environment variable, it won't connect. Same server selection error

Comment: The issue I'm facing is not featured in there, so that reference doesn't really help

Comment: will search relevant links for time out issues and get back to you

Comment: Troubleshoot [time](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/data-factory/connector-troubleshoot-mongodb.md) Out [reference](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-timeout-error/216297/3) [link](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/connect-timeout-and-execution-timeout-in-nodejs-driver/2129)